# g++ warning "defined but not used" on global const, depending on optimization flags

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, constants, linkage

Consider the following:

```
// headher h.h
#pragma once
namespace foo {
    const float c1 = 0.22;
    inline float f() {  return c1; }
    const float c2 = f();
    const float c3 = 0.33;
}
// source lib.cpp
#include "h.h"
```

Build a shared library with:

```
g++ -Wall -O2 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libme.so -o libme.so lib.cpp
```

The compiler (5.4.0) complains with:

`h.h:9:13: warning: ‘foo::c2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]`

Why the warning? <s>Don't they have external linkage?</s>

Why only `c2` ? There is no warning about `c3`.

Note that the warning goes away without optimization flags (`-O0`) (?!?)

(I know I could use `constexpr`, but in the real code I might have a non-literal type, so `constexpr` is no good)

EDIT:

Ok, consts in C++ have internal linkage (thanks Richard Critten). But my questions remain:

Why is there a warning about `c2` and not about `c3`?

What is the "expected" compiler response? A warning or not? I would not expect any defined-but-not-used warning for constants in a header, that anyone could include to have access to them (so it makes not sense to warn a priori about no usage)

Comment: _"...Don't they have external linkage?..."_: _"...The const qualifier used on a declaration of a non-local non-volatile variable that is not declared extern gives it __internal linkage__. This is different from C where const file scope variables have external linkage...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: Anyone? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Seems closely related to [g++-5.1.1 warns about unused variable only when optimization flag is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917767/g-5-1-1-warns-about-unused-variable-only-when-optimization-flag-is-used) (the warning only shows in GCC 5, later versions need `-Wunused-const-variable` and then warn on `c3` instead...)

Comment: I think there is a GCC attribute for this situation that tells GCC to ensure the symbol is exported and it will be used later. GCC should not discard the symbol.

Comment: Which attribute would that be?